# How to parse a JsonString into key value pairs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, parsing

I have a PostRequest here that I want to be able to save data to different tables. About the @RequestBody I get a JsonString that I want to split to be able to execute an INSERT INTO query.

Here is my PostRequest:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/config/test/{tableName}/{schemaName}")
    public String postValue(@RequestBody String values, @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName, @PathVariable("schemaName") String schemaName) {
        String keyString = "";
        String valueString = "";
        final String sql = "INSERT INTO " + schemaName + "." + tableName + "(" + keyString + ") VALUES(" + valueString + ")";
        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.executeUpdate();
        return values;
    }
```

And here's my JSONString:

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "indexNummer": 4,
    "indexName": "Gewichtung Alter Periode ohne Maßnahmen",
    "minVal": 51.0,
    "maxVal": 85.0,
    "indexWert": 1
}
```

Is there any way to split my string so that my two strings keyString, valueString are filled as follows?

keyString = "id,indexNumber,indexName,minVal,maxVal,indexValue"
valueString="23,4, "Is there any way to split my string so that my two strings keyString, valueString are filled as follows?

keyString = "id, indexNumber, indexName, minVal, maxVal, indexValue"

valueString="23, 4, "Gewichtung Alter Periode ohne Maßnahmen", 51.0, 85.0, 1"

Comment: There are a lot of libraries available for parsing json. Jackson, gson, jsonb...  Pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert JSONString into Map or you can directly read it is map and then do the following

```
@PostMapping(value = "/config/test/{tableName}/{schemaName}")
public Map postValue(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> values, @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName, 
@PathVariable("schemaName") String schemaName) {
        String keyString = "";
        String valueString = "";

        Set<String> keySet = values.keySet();

        for (String key : keySet) {

            // add comma after first key-value pair only.
            if (keyString.length() > 0) {
                keyString += ",";
                valueString += ",";
            }

            keyString += key;

            Object valueObj = values.get(key);
            if (valueObj instanceof String) {
                valueString = valueString + "\"" + valueObj.toString() + "\"";
            } else if (valueObj instanceof Integer) {
                Integer valueInt = (Integer) valueObj;
                valueString = valueString + valueInt;
            } else if (valueObj instanceof Double) {
                Double valueDouble = (Double) valueObj;
                valueString = valueString + valueDouble;
            }
        }

        final String sql = "INSERT INTO " + schemaName + "." + tableName + "(" + keyString + ") VALUES(" + valueString + ")";
        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.executeUpdate();
        return values;
}
```

Comment: Wow that works very well, thank you. But I still have one last question. If I have a value in the json string as a string then it is displayed in double quotes. But in my postgresql database only single quotes are allowed for string. 
Can I convert the double quotes in strings into single quotes?

Comment: Of course, you can convert. Change `valueString = valueString + "\"" + valueObj.toString() + "\"";` to `valueString = valueString + "'" + valueObj.toString() + "'";`. It should work. Kindly accept the answer and upvote if it helps.

Comment: May I ask one more question? I am also trying to write a method that updates data in the database. For this I have to parse the string JSON so that I get a string that looks like this:
    index_number= 4, index_name='Gewichtung Alter Periode ohne Maßnahmen',min_val= 51.0,max_val= 111.0,index_value= 2

How do I manage to arrange the values in this notation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` as below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper =new ObjectMapper();
        
        String string="{\r\n"
                + "    \"id\": 23,\r\n"
                + "    \"indexNummer\": 4,\r\n"
                + "    \"indexName\": \"Gewichtung Alter Periode ohne Maßnahmen\",\r\n"
                + "    \"minVal\": 51.0,\r\n"
                + "    \"maxVal\": 85.0,\r\n"
                + "    \"indexWert\": 1\r\n"
                + "}";
        
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        };
        HashMap<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(string, typeRef);
        String keys = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        String values = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println(keys);
        System.out.println(values);
```

Output :

> indexNummer,maxVal,minVal,indexName,id,indexWert
>
> 4,85.0,51.0,Gewichtung Alter Periode ohne Maßnahmen,23,1